# key listeners not working while im running a while loop my paint method

Tags: java

I am new to Java.I got to know that keylisteners and paint methods run on a seperate thread called EDT.But in my situation i need to run a while loop in a paint method for a while but during that running of a loop i need to listen to my incoming keys.Can u sugest me a good way so as i can run my loop as well as listen keys during the time the loop runs.I'm actually creating a loop to fire a bullet in a game im designing.So any other suggestions

```
about the making of the thing work would be helpful!!!!thanx in advance`enter code here
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class aadil extends Screen implements KeyListener {
public int i=0,j=0,condition=0,l=0;
int a=0,b=0;
Screen s=new Screen();

    public static void main(String aadil[]){
        DisplayMode dm=new DisplayMode(800,600,16,DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
        aadil a=new aadil();
        a.run(dm);
    }
    public void run(DisplayMode dm){
        setBackground(Color.red);
        setForeground(Color.blue);
        setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,44));

                try{
            s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
            Window w= s.getFullScreenWindow();
            w.addKeyListener(this);
            try{
                //Thread.sleep(9000);
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
        finally{
            //s.restore();
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        //if(i==10){
        //while(a<750){
        if(a>i)
        g.clearRect(50+i+10, 60+j, 120, 120);

        if(a<i) g.clearRect(50+i-10, 60+j, 120, 120);
        if(b>j)
            g.clearRect(50+i, 60+j+10, 120, 120);
        if(b<j) g.clearRect(50+i, 60+j-10, 120, 120);

        g.fillRect(50+i, 60+j, 120, 120);

        a=i;
        b=j;
        //a+=9;

        if(l==1){
    //  while(condition<400){
        g.setColor(Color.blue);

        g.fillRect(170+i+condition, 120+j, 30, 20);
        try{
        Thread.sleep(700);
        g.clearRect(170+i+condition, 120+j, 30, 20);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        condition+=19;
        //}
        //l=0;
        }
        //g.fillRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
        //}

        //}
        //if(i==20){
            //g.fillRect(200, 300, 120, 60);

        //}

    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int keycode=e.getKeyCode();
        //System.out.print(keycode);

        if(keycode==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        i-=10;
        if(keycode==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            i+=10;
        if(keycode==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            j-=10;
            if(keycode==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){

                    j+=10;
            }
            if(keycode==KeyEvent.VK_A)
            l=1;
            condition=0;
        //s.restore();
        repaint();



    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}`
```

Comment: Without reading your code, the thing that comes to mind from your description is to run your loop in its own new `Thread`

Comment: ya i did it but its of no use i added the following below code to shoot my bullet                                                             public void paintbullet()
 {
  l=1;
  Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){

   @Override
   public void run() {
    repaint();
    
   }
   
   
  });
  
  t1.start();
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

You need to run both code snippets in different Threads,
If you have a while loop running, the thread will not reach the code after the while loop until it is done.

My suggestion is to put the paint method for your bullets in a separate class that will be run in it's own thread. You can then listen for events and paint at the same time.

Comment: ya i did but itsnt working properly i added the following code to run tht loop in a different threadpublic void paintbullet()
 {
  l=1;
  Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){

   @Override
   public void run() {
    repaint();
    
   }
   
   
  });
  
  t1.start();
  
 }

Comment: I suggest actually making a new Threaded class to seperate your code.